# Visual Studio: Custom Syntax Coloring

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-extensions

Most programming language options in Visual Studio have built-in **syntax coloring**. However, I am required to use Assembly Language for my purpose. I have tried various Assembly Language syntax highlighting extensions, but some data types wouldn't be colored properly. How can I implement my own syntax highlighter/colorer? Would it require the development of a Visual Studio Extensions project?

Comment: Already written for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Henk-JanLebbink.AsmDude or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Trass3r.AsmHighlighter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I implement my own syntax highlighter/colorer? Would it require the development of a Visual Studio Extensions project?

you can use related visual studio extension from visual studio marketplace. like below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=13xforever.language-x86-64-assembly

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Trass3r.AsmHighlighter

You could also create your Syntax Coloring in Custom Editors, For more information, please refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165803.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer (plus 1)